# How can i hide default shown labels from GMap.net Map

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gmap.net

I am working in GMap.net's in wpf and able to show Map on a canvas. I am able to show different map provider's Map on the Canvas. But, When the map tile is loaded successfully then the default place names provided by the providers is shown in the Map. I want to hide all those names of places from the Map because i do not want user to see the whole place names. I want to show only the custom names of places which i want to show to the user.

I have done these things:

```
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasMain" Grid.Row="1">
        <src:Map x:Name="MainMap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 CanDragMap="True"
                 Bearing="1"
                 Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=CanvasMain}"
                 Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=CanvasMain}">

        </src:Map>
    </Canvas>
```

In code behind:

```
        MainMap.MapProvider = GoogleMapProvider.Instance;

        MainMap.SetPositionByKeywords("India");
        MainMap.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;

        MainMap.MinZoom = 3;
        MainMap.MaxZoom = 17;

        MainMap.Zoom = 8.0;
        MainMap.ShowCenter = true;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you have no influence on the map imagery and its specific content layers from a provider. They come rendered as they are.

Your only choice is to choose a different provider with less textual detail.